# How to hide LinkItem title in smart gwt

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, smartgwt

I'm new to smart gwt and I'm a bit puzzled by a title that is appearing next to a LinkItem. Here is a screen shot of that

[image]

As u can see, "Download Template" is the one that is giving me a head ache. Please tell how to remove this thing. I tried removing the title but it sail isc_ListItem_0 in the place where Download Template. I also tried providing null as a parameter to setTitle but to no avail. Please Help Me!!! Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer myself! All you need to do is set `setShowTitle(false)`